# Protect excel with password from vba

Tags: vba, excel

I want to design **VBA code** that *protects excel document with password*.

I know its possible with excel tools and its more secure, but I want to try this and use it in other projects.

I wrote this code

```
vPass = InputBox("Password : ")
If StrComp(vPass, "predefinedPass") <> 0 Then Application.Quit
```

But when I put it in `Workbook_Open`, the content of the file is still showing while while waiting for user to give password.

I don't want the content of file to be shown.

Any ideas??

Comment: Of course this won't protect the workbook as any user can open the workbook with macros disabled.

Comment: How to open workbook with macros disabled. and how to prevent user from doing that??

Comment: @OuldAbba You don't put simply, Excel has a built in option to secure a file with a password, is there some reason why that wouldn't be suitable?

Comment: I know it has security option, and i know it 'perfect'. But I wanted this so i can run some actions before user can access the document. And now it OK.

Comment: "How to open workbook with macros disabled" - if a user configures macro security in Excel to anything other than "Low", then as a minimum he will be prompted to run macros or not.  There's no way to prevent this: google for "open workbook without running macro"

Comment: I think this code is being used with the assumption that the file is "Macro enabled Workbook"

Comment: Yes, you're right @xtechkid . In fact its not just for security, I use  also to customize sheets depending on user responses at start-up. its just for simple users who don't know about 'open workbook without running macro'

Comment: @OuldAbba As Joe mentioned, unless Excel security is set to low then the user will see a prompt, if they are "simple" users as you say, they may well click disable because they are cautious of clicking enable as they don't know what Macro's are?

Comment: Oops, I missed that @MattDonnan. So there is no way to run code at start-up without preventing user.

Comment: @OuldAbba Unless security is set to low, or the excel file is digitally signed (trusted) then no

Comment: *digitally signed*, that's interesting... is it possible for individuals to do that or it needs Microsoft's certificate?

Comment: @OuldAbba If you are distributing to other parties then you would need to be registered with Microsoft, however you can sign your own internal office projects, I don't bother to be honest though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is simple before firing the event set

```
    Application.Screenupdating = False
```

once the condition is true set screenupdating back to true

Comment: Yes, that does the job. But i also had to use `Workbooks("myWorkbook"). Close` before `Application.Quit` to completely make the content disappear.